# How do I pass a List<Map<String,String>> using putExtra to another intent

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my project I have a AsyncTask that fetches some JSON data from the net, from which I build a

```
List<Map<String,String>> typesCategory = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

I now need to pass this List to my next intent. Looking at the API, I dont see any methods that support passing a list.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
        protected void onPostExecute(List result) {
            progress.dismiss();
            Intent action = new Intent(this, ListTypeActivity.class);
            action.putExtra("data", result);

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arbitrary data can be passed along via `Bundle`, `Parcelable`, or `Serializable`, whichever fits your needs. In case of Parcelable, you can even pass an array of them.

Also, `ArrayList` already implements `Serializable`, and so do most `Map` implementations.